# KDB get substring

Tags: kdb

How can I add a column containing a substring of a another columns containing symbols. So, go from

```
 t:flip `date`sym`pos!(`d1`d1`d1`d2;`aaaA1`bbbA1`aaaA2`aaaA3;1 2 3 1)

 date    sym    pos
 d1    aaaA1    1
 d1    bbA1     2
 d1    aaaA2    3
 d2    aaaA3    1
```

to

```
t:flip `date`sym`pos`ext!(`d1`d1`d1`d2;`aaaA1`bbbA1`aaaA2`aaaA3;1 2 3 1;`aaa`bbb`aaa`aaa)

date    sym   pos   ext
d1      aaaA1   1   aaa
d1      bbA1    2   bb
d1      aaaA2   3   aaa
d2      aaaA3   1   aaa
```

EDIT. The substring should always contain the first len(symbol) -2 characters, so in my example above, aaa for aaaAx and bb for bbAx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the substring you wish to extract is a constant length, you can do something like this following:

```
q)t:flip `date`sym`pos!(`d1`d1`d1`d2;`aaaA1`bbbA1`aaaA2`aaaA3;1 2 3 1)
q)update ext:`$3#'string sym from t
date sym   pos ext
------------------
d1   aaaA1 1   aaa
d1   bbbA1 2   bbb
d1   aaaA2 3   aaa
d2   aaaA3 1   aaa
```

If that's not the case, please provide some more detail with regards to how the substring to be extracted can be identified

Hope this helps

Jonathon

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I provided more details about the substring in the edit

Comment: In this case you could use

`update ext:\`$-2_'string sym from t`

Answer (score 1):

There can be a clever way of applying this below, but this is what i first came up with.

```
t:flip `date`sym`pos!(`d1`d1`d1`d2;`aaaA1`bbbA1`aaaA2`aaaA3;1 2 3 1)
t: update ctr: {-2 + count string x} each sym from t;
t:{[x] :update ext:x[`ctr]#string(x[`sym]) from x} each t;
```

2nd line is applying your logic of: len(symbol) - 2 
3rd line is taking 'ctr' number of characters from the original symbol characters.

Comment: ah, sweet... I got to the second line based on Jonathon's answer, but I couldnt get it to work in the update. Didnt know '{ } each t '. Thanks

Comment: if you are running this to really large dataset (~hundreds of millions of lines), the performance can be an issue because the above code is passing each row to the function. in that case, you may want to optimise the code.. other cases i think it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Using [drop](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/drop/):

```
q)t:flip `date`sym`pos!(`d1`d1`d1`d2;`aaaA1`bbA1`aaaA2`aaaA3;1 2 3 1)
q)update ext:`$-2_'string sym from t
date sym   pos ext
------------------
d1   aaaA1 1   aaa
d1   bbA1  2   bb 
d1   aaaA2 3   aaa
d2   aaaA3 1   aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t say so, but this is kdb+, so let’s assume:

- your table is long
- your `sym` column has duplicates

You don’t need to convert all the symbols to strings and back: only the distinct ones. (In this example, I’ve changed one of the symbols to create a duplicate.)

```
q)t:flip `date`sym`pos!(`d1`d1`d1`d2;`aaaA1`bbbA1`aaaA2`aaaA1;1 2 3 1)
q)update ext:{nub:distinct x;(`$-2 _'string nub)nub?x}sym from t
date sym   pos ext
------------------
d1   aaaA1 1   aaa
d1   bbbA1 2   bbb
d1   aaaA2 3   aaa
d2   aaaA1 1   aaa
```

The [utility `.Q.fu`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qfu-apply-unique) applies a function to the distinct items.

```
q)update ext:.Q.fu[{`$-2 _'string x};sym] from t
date sym   pos ext
------------------
d1   aaaA1 1   aaa
d1   bbbA1 2   bbb
d1   aaaA2 3   aaa
d2   aaaA1 1   aaa
```

This operation would be faster if the `sym` column were already stored as an [enumeration](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/enums/), because the distinct values would then be available without calculation.